# Cannot add a foreign key to exists table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I cannot add a foreign key to my exists table. I want to add a foreign key `publisher_id` from table `games` references to `publishers` (`publisher_id`).

But when running the below sql, it says:

> Source and target columns must have the same data type, there must be an index on the target columns and referenced data must exist.
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vngarena.com`.`#sql-818_1b1`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-818_1b1_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`) REFERENCES `publishers` (`publisher_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

The sql is:

> ALTER TABLE `games`
>   ADD FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`) REFERENCES `publishers` (`publisher_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

And here is the diagram of my db:

[image]

More info:
- Table `games` has two records
- Table `games` has other foreign key which references to table `gamecats` (`gamecat_id`)
- Table `gamecats` has two records
- Table `publishers` has no record

Comment: Those two records in table `games`...do they have any values in the column `publisher_id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is any existing data that violates the relationship, you will need to clean it up before adding the key.

**[Edited]**

After your edit:  The publisher_id in Table games, is looking for a match in the publishers table.  Add a publisher with an id that matches what's in the games table.

Comment: Yes, because of the default value for column `publisher_id` in table `games` is 0, and table `publishers` has no any record to matches with child records. So when add a foreign key `publisher_id` to `games`, it failed. I have to insert a record to table `publishers` then update its primary to 0, then add foreign key to table `games`, and it worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the games table records before adding foreign key.

If you add foreign key,it should match with existing data. In your condition the publishers table has no records . so it will fails `foreign key` if you add data with records in games table

```
                             or
```

You should add two records in publishers table with same keys exists in games table.

For more detail, refer below link
[Foreign Key](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_Create_foreign_key_contraints.php)

Comment: Yes, I dont want to delete my data, so I have a solution that posted in the comment above.

Comment: @NguyễnTrọngBằng. Ya both way correct. If you don't need to delete,you should add matched publisher_id records in publisher id table..